# Resizable BorderPane w/ Drawer in JavaFX

Tags: java, layout, javafx

I am trying to make a resizable BorderPane with Drawer on the Left. I made a transition that shifts the "left AnchorPane" to the outside - but unfortunately the left place-holder for the BorderPane does not resize/ shift/ or collapse. I was hoping it would do one.

Anyways, here are some pics that better describes what is happening. Notice the white space in the first picture. That is the problem.

Drawer In
[image]

Drawer Out
[image]

Java

```
import java.io.IOException;

import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXHamburger;
import com.jfoenix.transitions.hamburger.HamburgerBasicCloseTransition;

import javafx.animation.TranslateTransition;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class ResizeableBorderPane extends BorderPane {  

    @FXML
    private BorderPane root;

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane topAnchor;

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane leftAnchor;

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane centerAnchor;

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane rightAnchor;

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane bottomAnchor;

    @FXML
    private JFXHamburger hamburger;

    private Stage stage;

    public ResizeableBorderPane(){

        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass()
                    .getResource("/application/prototypes/custom/resizableborderpane/ResizableBorderPaneView.fxml"));
            loader.setController(this);
            loader.setRoot(this);
            loader.load();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        root.setPrefWidth(1000);
        root.setPrefHeight(800);

        setStage();
    }

    @FXML
    public void initialize() {

        leftAnchor.setPrefWidth(200);
        topAnchor.setPrefHeight(50);
        bottomAnchor.setPrefHeight(50);

        final TranslateTransition translateLeftAnchor =
                new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(1000), leftAnchor);

        translateLeftAnchor.setFromX(50);
        translateLeftAnchor.setToX(-200 + 50);  
        translateLeftAnchor.play();

        HamburgerBasicCloseTransition burgerTask = new HamburgerBasicCloseTransition(hamburger);
        burgerTask.setRate(-1);

        hamburger.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED,(e)->{

            if (burgerTask.getRate() == -1){
                burgerTask.setRate(burgerTask.getRate()*-1);
                burgerTask.play();

                translateLeftAnchor.setFromX(-200 + 50);
                translateLeftAnchor.setToX(0);

                translateLeftAnchor.play();

            } else {

                burgerTask.setRate(burgerTask.getRate()*-1);
                burgerTask.play();

                translateLeftAnchor.setFromX(0);
                translateLeftAnchor.setToX(-200 + 50);

                translateLeftAnchor.play();
            }           
        });

        translateLeftAnchor.currentTimeProperty().addListener( e -> {

            System.out.println("Layout X: " + leftAnchor.getTranslateX());

        });
    }

    // =========== GETTERS AND SETTERS ===========

    public Stage getStage(){
        return (Stage) root.getScene().getWindow();
    }

    public void setStage(){
        try{
            this.stage = (Stage) root.getScene().getWindow();
        } catch (NullPointerException n){
            System.out.println("The stage is null!");
        }
    }

    public BorderPane getRoot() {
        return root;
    }

    public void setRoot(BorderPane root) {
        this.root = root;
    }

    public AnchorPane getTopAnchor() {
        return topAnchor;
    }

    public void setTopAnchor(AnchorPane topAnchor) {
        this.topAnchor = topAnchor;
    }

    public AnchorPane getLeftAnchor() {
        return leftAnchor;
    }

    public void setLeftAnchor(AnchorPane leftAnchor) {
        this.leftAnchor = leftAnchor;
    }

    public AnchorPane getCenterAnchor() {
        return centerAnchor;
    }

    public void setCenterAnchor(AnchorPane centerAnchor) {
        this.centerAnchor = centerAnchor;
    }

    public AnchorPane getRightAnchor() {
        return rightAnchor;
    }

    public void setRightAnchor(AnchorPane rightAnchor) {
        this.rightAnchor = rightAnchor;
    }

    public AnchorPane getBottomAnchor() {
        return bottomAnchor;
    }

    public void setBottomAnchor(AnchorPane bottomAnchor) {
        this.bottomAnchor = bottomAnchor;
    }
}
```

FXML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXHamburger?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>

<fx:root fx:id="root" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" type="BorderPane" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <top>
      <AnchorPane fx:id="topAnchor" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" style="-fx-background-color: #999999;" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <JFXHamburger fx:id="hamburger" alignment="CENTER_LEFT" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="5.0" />
         </children></AnchorPane>
   </top>
   <left>
      <AnchorPane fx:id="leftAnchor" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" style="-fx-background-color: #FF0000;" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </left>
   <center>
      <AnchorPane fx:id="centerAnchor" focusTraversable="true" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="200.0" minWidth="200.0" style="-fx-background-color: #454545;" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER_LEFT" />
   </center>
   <right>
      <AnchorPane fx:id="rightAnchor" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" style="-fx-background-color: #00FF00;" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </right>
   <bottom>
      <AnchorPane fx:id="bottomAnchor" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" style="-fx-background-color: #0000FF;" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </bottom>
</fx:root>
```

Any suggestions on how to fix the white space please? I am a little stuck.

**UPDATE**

I have it almost working by adding this line in the time property listener:

```
translateLeftAnchor.currentTimeProperty().addListener( e -> {

            setMargin(leftAnchor, new Insets(0, leftAnchor.translateXProperty().doubleValue(), 0, 0));
        });
```

However, when the drawer goes in - it moves a little faster than the "center" expands; thus, one can see a white line in between.

[image]

**UPDATE 2**

Used the translate property listener and it works fine

```
leftAnchor.translateXProperty().addListener( e -> {

    setMargin(leftAnchor, new Insets(0, leftAnchor.translateXProperty().doubleValue(), 0, 0));
});
```

Comment: Try to `setManaged(false)` on the side menu when it is not in use, that might redraw the other block into that space. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setManaged-boolean-

Comment: @Chris Thank you for the suggestion but i could not get it to work nicely. However, I added an update which has a little problem but it is almost the correct behavior. The center expands and shrinks with the left.

Comment: I noticed your last edit seems to have fixed your issue, I'd recommend posting that as an answer and accepting it for future users :) Also good job on figuring it out

Comment: @Chris Thank you! Let me clean it up first and I will post it if everything is still okay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution above seems to work great for me. Enhance it as you wish. Here is my working example.

**Java**

```
package application.prototypes.custom.resizableborderpane;

import java.io.IOException;

import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXHamburger;
import com.jfoenix.transitions.hamburger.HamburgerBasicCloseTransition;

import javafx.animation.TranslateTransition;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class ResizeableBorderPane extends BorderPane {  

    @FXML
    private BorderPane root;

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane topAnchor;

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane leftAnchor;

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane centerAnchor;

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane rightAnchor;

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane bottomAnchor;

    @FXML
    private JFXHamburger hamburger;

    private Stage stage;

    public ResizeableBorderPane(){

        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass()
                    .getResource("/application/prototypes/custom/resizableborderpane/ResizableBorderPaneView.fxml"));
            loader.setController(this);
            loader.setRoot(this);
            loader.load();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        root.setPrefWidth(1000);
        root.setPrefHeight(600);
    }

    @FXML
    public void initialize() {

        leftAnchor.setPrefWidth(200);
        leftAnchor.setTranslateX(-150);
        setMargin(leftAnchor, new Insets(0, leftAnchor.translateXProperty().doubleValue(), 0, 0));

        topAnchor.setPrefHeight(50);
        bottomAnchor.setPrefHeight(50);
        rightAnchor.setPrefWidth(50);

        final TranslateTransition translateLeftAnchor =
                new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(500), leftAnchor);

        HamburgerBasicCloseTransition burgerTask = new HamburgerBasicCloseTransition(hamburger);
        burgerTask.setRate(-1);

        hamburger.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED,(e)->{

            if (burgerTask.getRate() == -1){
                burgerTask.setRate(burgerTask.getRate()*-1);
                burgerTask.play();

                translateLeftAnchor.setFromX(-200 + 50);
                translateLeftAnchor.setToX(0);

                translateLeftAnchor.play();

            } else {

                burgerTask.setRate(burgerTask.getRate()*-1);
                burgerTask.play();

                translateLeftAnchor.setFromX(0);
                translateLeftAnchor.setToX(-200 + 50);

                translateLeftAnchor.play();
            }           
        });

        leftAnchor.translateXProperty().addListener( e -> {

            setMargin(leftAnchor, new Insets(0, leftAnchor.translateXProperty().doubleValue(), 0, 0));
        });
    }

    // =========== GETTERS AND SETTERS ===========

    public Stage getStage(){
        return (Stage) root.getScene().getWindow();
    }

    public BorderPane getRoot() {
        return root;
    }

    public AnchorPane getTopAnchor() {
        return topAnchor;
    }

    public AnchorPane getLeftAnchor() {
        return leftAnchor;
    }

    public AnchorPane getCenterAnchor() {
        return centerAnchor;
    }

    public AnchorPane getRightAnchor() {
        return rightAnchor;
    }

    public AnchorPane getBottomAnchor() {
        return bottomAnchor;
    }
}
```

**FXML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXHamburger?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>

<fx:root fx:id="root" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" type="BorderPane" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <top>
      <AnchorPane fx:id="topAnchor" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" style="-fx-background-color: #999999;" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <JFXHamburger fx:id="hamburger" alignment="CENTER_LEFT" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="5.0" />
         </children></AnchorPane>
   </top>
   <left>
      <AnchorPane fx:id="leftAnchor" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" style="-fx-background-color: #FF0000;" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER_LEFT" />
   </left>
   <center>
      <AnchorPane fx:id="centerAnchor" focusTraversable="true" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="200.0" minWidth="200.0" style="-fx-background-color: #454545;" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER_LEFT" />
   </center>
   <right>
      <AnchorPane fx:id="rightAnchor" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" style="-fx-background-color: #00FF00;" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </right>
   <bottom>
      <AnchorPane fx:id="bottomAnchor" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" style="-fx-background-color: #0000FF;" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </bottom>
</fx:root>
```